# Terraform ECS Task Definition - Dynamic Nested EFS Volumes

Tags: terraform

I am attempting to use terraform modules with ECS. The issue is that for some applications I will need an EFS volume defined in the task definition and in others I won't want it at all. I need a way to add a volume block conditionally. I've tried nested dynamic blocks and can't get them to work.

Here's the dynamic nested volume configuration block:

```
  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    content {
      name = volume.key
      host_path = volume.value.host_path

      dynamic "efs_volume_configuration" {
        for_each = volume.value.efs_volume_configuration
        content {
          file_system_id = efs_volume_configuration.value.file_system_id

          dynamic "authorization_config" {
            for_each = efs_volume_configuration.value.authorization_config
            content {
              access_point_id = authorization_config.value.access_point_id
              iam = authorization_config.value.iam
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is my variable (I;ve changed this so many times but still can't get it right):

```
variable "volumes" {
  description = "(Optional) A set of volume blocks that containers in your task may use"
  type = list(object({
    host_path = string
    name      = string
    efs_volume_configuration = list(object({
      file_system_id          = string
      authorization_config = list(object({
        access_point_id = string
        iam             = string
      }))
    }))
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Here is where I declared the value for the volume block in the application I want it in:

```
  volumes = [{
    name      = "efs-storage-rasa"
    host_path = "/model"
    efs_volume_configuration = [{
      file_system_id         = aws_efs_file_system.filessystem.id
      authorization_config = [{
        access_point_id    = aws_efs_access_point.filessystem_access_point.id
        iam                = "ENABLED"
      }]
    }]
  }]
```

**Note**: THis is just a test stack I threw together real quick to see if I can get this to work. All I need is to be able to conditionally add an EFS volume block to an ECS service. I don't want to create two modules for an ECS service (one for when a volume is required and one for when a volume is not required) is I can avoid it.

Thank yoU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team actually had this exact same issue. Here's how we solved it in the resource declaration:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "this" {
  family                   = var.family      # Naming our first task
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]     # Stating that we are using ECS Fargate
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"        # Using awsvpc as our network mode as this is required for Fargate
  memory                   = var.task_memory # Specifying the hard limit of memory for our task
  cpu                      = var.task_cpu    # Specifying the hard limit of CPU for our task
  execution_role_arn       = var.ecs_task_exec_arn
  task_role_arn            = var.ecs_task_role_arn

  # Created a policy in the templates folder
  container_definitions = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/${var.template}.tmpl",
    {
      "name"           = var.container_name
      "username"       = var.username
      "password"       = var.password
      "region"         = var.region
      "memory"         = var.container_memory
      "cpu"            = var.container_cpu
      "container_path" = var.container_path
      "source_volume"  = var.source_volume
  })

  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volume
    content {
      name = volume.value.source_volume

      dynamic "efs_volume_configuration" {
        for_each = volume.value.efs_volume_configuration

        content {
          file_system_id = efs_volume_configuration.value.efs_file_system_id
          transit_encryption = efs_volume_configuration.value.transit_encryption

          dynamic "authorization_config" {
            for_each = efs_volume_configuration.value.authorization_config

            content {
              access_point_id = authorization_config.value.access_point_id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how we configured it in the module call:

```
volume = [
    {
      source_volume = "jenkins_home"
      efs_volume_configuration = [
        {
          efs_file_system_id = module.jenkins-efs.efs_file_system_id
          transit_encryption = "ENABLED"
          authorization_config = [
            {
              access_point_id = module.jenkins-efs.efs_access_point_id
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here's how we set up our variables:

```
variable "efs_access_point_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The ID associated with the EFS access point."
  default     = null
}

variable "efs_file_system_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The ID associated with EFS."
  default     = null
}

variable "transit_encryption" {
  type        = string
  description = "Whether or not to set transit encryption to ENABLE or DISABLED."
  default     = null
}

variable "transit_encryption_port" {
  type        = number
  description = "Port used for transit encryption. 2049 for EFS."
  default     = null
}

variable "volume" {
  description = "Used for a dynamic volume block for ECS service."
  type        = any
  default     = []
}

variable "load_balancer" {
  description = "Used for a dynamic load balancer block for ECS service."
  type        = any
  default     = []
}
```

We've also taken a similar approach for only needing one service that can either create or not create a load balancer:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "this" {
  name            = var.name
  tags            = var.tags
  cluster         = var.cluster
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.this.arn # Referencing the task our service will spin up
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count   = var.desired_count # If number exceeds AZs, launches round robin (13 means 3 in AZ1, 2 in others with 6 subnets/AZs)

  # load_balancer {
  #   target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn
  #   container_name   = var.container_name
  #   container_port   = var.container_port # This port must be exposed by the underlying container and should be used for health checks
  # }

  dynamic "load_balancer" {
    for_each = var.load_balancer

    content {
      target_group_arn = load_balancer.value.target_group_arn
      container_name   = load_balancer.value.container_name
      container_port   = load_balancer.value.container_port
    }
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = var.subnets
    assign_public_ip = var.assign_public_ip # Determines if our containers launch with public IPs
    security_groups  = ["${aws_security_group.service_security_group.id}"]
  }

  health_check_grace_period_seconds = var.health_check_grace_period
  enable_execute_command            = var.enable_execute_command # Enable AWS Exec to be used on Fargate containers as a break glass to retrieve configs
  force_new_deployment              = var.force_new_deployment   # Require the service to create a new task so that break glass is activated

}
```

Here's how we call it in our aws_ecs_service resource:

```
  # Testing using a dynamic configuration block for load balancers
  load_balancer = [
    {
      target_group_arn = module.alb-web.target_group_arns[0]
      container_name   = "test"
      container_port   = 443
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Hey Graham! Thanks so much for your detailed response! I ended up figuring it out but never posted my answer back to this forum, so I've accepted your answer since it's detailed and looks great! I appreciate the extra load balancer example as well :)

Comment: This is absolutely bang on. I was mentally bracing myself for a long day of failing, and this sorted my issue instantly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes == null ? [] : [1]
    content {
      name = volume.key
      host_path = volume.value.host_path

      dynamic "efs_volume_configuration" {
        for_each = volume.value.efs_volume_configuration
        content {
          file_system_id = efs_volume_configuration.value.file_system_id

          dynamic "authorization_config" {
            for_each = efs_volume_configuration.value.authorization_config
            content {
              access_point_id = authorization_config.value.access_point_id
              iam = authorization_config.value.iam
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that and am now getting: 
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../modules/ecs_module/main.tf line 109, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service":
│  109:         for_each = volume.value.efs_volume_configuration
│     ├────────────────
│     │ volume.value is 1
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.